# System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Single'.'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net

Estoy trabajando con una matriz que muestre los valores de las calificaciones y donde el usuario pueda modificar tres elementos de la matriz y asi mostrar el promedio de las calificaciones.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace Practica_3
{
 class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ArrayList calificaciones = new ArrayList();

    //entrada de datos
    calificaciones.Add(5);
    calificaciones.Add(5);
    calificaciones.Add(10);
    calificaciones.Add(8);
    calificaciones.Add(3);
    calificaciones.Add(4);
    calificaciones.Add(2);
    calificaciones.Add(1);
    calificaciones.Add(20);
    calificaciones.Add(1);
    //mostramos matriz original
    Console.WriteLine("****************** MATRIZ CALIFICACIONES ********************\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < calificaciones.Count; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(  calificaciones[i] + " ");
    }

    //usuario modifica los elementos de la matriz
    Console.WriteLine("\n\nModifique e ingrese la calificaciones correctas para los elementos [8], [9] y [1]");
    Console.WriteLine("calificacion [8]:");
    float ocho = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("calificacion [9]:");
    float nueve = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("calificacion [1]:");
    float uno = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    calificaciones[8] = ocho;
    calificaciones[9] = nueve;
    calificaciones[1] = uno;

    //Sumar las notas
    float suma = 0;

    foreach (float nota in calificaciones)
        suma += nota;
    //Escribir los resultados
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("El promedio es de " + suma / calificaciones.Count);
  }
 }
}
```

Justamente en esta linea recibo el siguiente error: System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Single'.'

```
foreach (float nota in calificaciones)
```

Intenté cambiar las variables a double, en vez de float pero recibo un error similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema consistia en que estaba inicializando con tipos de datos diferentes el ArrayList, por defecto como *int* pero luego estabas introduciendo valores float en el *ArrayList*

Lo mejor seria inicializar una lista diciendole especificamente que vas a almacenar
*float*.

En la linea siguiente utilizar var en vez de un tipo definido

```
foreach (var nota in calificaciones)
```

Tambien si deseas puedes utilizar *float* ahi, no va a afectar en este caso

```
foreach (float nota in calificaciones)
```

Codigo completo

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            List<float> calificaciones = new List<float>();

            //entrada de datos
            calificaciones.Add(5);
            calificaciones.Add(5);
            calificaciones.Add(10);
            calificaciones.Add(8);
            calificaciones.Add(3);
            calificaciones.Add(4);
            calificaciones.Add(2);
            calificaciones.Add(1);
            calificaciones.Add(20);
            calificaciones.Add(1);
            //mostramos matriz original
            Console.WriteLine("****************** MATRIZ CALIFICACIONES ********************\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < calificaciones.Count; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(calificaciones[i] + " ");
            }

            //usuario modifica los elementos de la matriz
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nModifique e ingrese la calificaciones correctas para los elementos [8], [9] y [1]");
            Console.WriteLine("calificacion [8]:");
            float ocho = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("calificacion [9]:");
            float nueve = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("calificacion [1]:");
            float uno = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            calificaciones[8] = ocho;
            calificaciones[9] = nueve;
            calificaciones[1] = uno;

            //Sumar las notas
            float suma = 0;

            foreach (var nota in calificaciones)
                suma += nota;
            //Escribir los resultados
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("El promedio es de " + suma / calificaciones.Count);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Gracias! Me ha ayudado mucho.

Comment: No te olvides de marcar como respuesta la pregunta y darle un voto :)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes simplificar mucho tu código haciendo uso de **Linq**.

Si lo que deseas es calcular él promedio lo único q debes hacer es esto:

```
var promedio = calificaciones.Average();
//Imprimir promedio
```

de esta forma evitas usar el **foreach** y hacer el cálculo tú mismo.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los usings:

```
using System.Linq;
```